# http-server gives warning message

Tags: httpserver

When I start up http-server as soon as I open the page I get:

```
node:25611) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Can someone provide specific instructions on:

1. How to (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2. How to fix the problem

Comment: How do you start your http-server and which is its version?

Comment: It's a cloud application https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/ide/5706c1976b98469a90e58bdadbf3e421?#  I just type in the terminal http-server  Version 0.12.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an open issue on `http-server` Github for that ([**#537**](https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/537)). In a nutshell, that's not even an issue of the package itself, but of one of its dependencies. And here's the catch:

> This is an issue in union (flatiron/union#64) which we're planning to
> remove from http-server down the road (#483). I'm not going to close
> this issue though, to ensure we make sure it goes away after #483 is
> resolved.

Now while that was written almost a year ago (Oct 24, 2019), both this issue and aforementioned [**#483**](https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/483) are still alive and kicking. So unless you really wish to downgrade to Node 10, you'll have to ignore that warning I suppose.